# Vue add directive only on condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add a directive only if a condition is met. Something like this, but without duplicate code

```
<v-text-field
    v-if="edit"
    v-model="name"
    append-icon="mdi-pencil"
    label="Name"
/>
<v-text-field
    v-else
    v-model="name"
    readonly
    label="Name"
/>
```

This took me way too long to figure this out, which is why I am posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way to do this is using a computed property, this way help you to keep a more readable and scalable code.

Here an example:

```
<template>
      <v-text-field
          v-model="name"
          :readonly="!edit"
          :append-icon="isEditing"
          label="Name"
        />
</template>

<script>

// Default Vue script code....

computed: {
  isEditing() {
    return this.edit ? 'mdi-pencil' : '';
  }
}
</script>
```

Other thing that you could do in your template is start using `CamelCase` instead of `kebab-case` for components, this can improve the readability of your code.

```
 <VTextField
        v-model="name"
        :readonly="!edit"
        :append-icon="isEditing"
        label="Name"
  />
```

Is only my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind any boolean directives directly and use conditionals for everything else.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="name"
    :readonly="!edit"
    :append-icon="edit ? 'mdi-pencil' : ''"
    label="Name"
/>
```